# MapView null in Fragment

Tags: android, dictionary, fragment

I have this xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:background="#f00"
android:gravity="center">

<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/map" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And this is my code in onCreateView method in Fragment

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_activity, container, false);
    mapView = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.map);
    mMap = mapView.getMap();

      if (mMap== null)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(),"Google Maps not Available",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

       locReader = (LocationReader) new LocationReader(getActivity().getBaseContext(), true);
       this.loc = locReader.getLastKnownLocation(); 
       moveCamMyPosition(loc);

    return view;
}
```

The Fragment load ok but nMap is null. The Toast appears "Google Maps not Available".

I can not find the error.

Comment: have you created the key and defined in menifest

Comment: on which device are you running this code? seems like you are using emulator.

Comment: @aldakur wrong layout inflated `map_activity`. is it same layout for fragment??

Comment: Yes. the name is not appropriate. In the last y launch map in Activity but now i want layout in Fragment

Answer (score 3):

Try to use `getMapAsync(OnMapReadyCallback callback)` instead of `getMap()`. http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView.html

```
public class myFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        /* ... */
        mapView.getMapAsync(this);
        /* ... */
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        /* do something with the map */
        mMap = map;
        locReader = (LocationReader) new LocationReader(getActivity().getBaseContext(), true);
        this.loc = locReader.getLastKnownLocation(); 
        moveCamMyPosition(loc);
    }
}
```

Comment: `nMap = mapView.getMapAsync(this)` "The method getMapAsync(OnMapReadyCallback callback) in te type mapView is not applicable for the arguments myFragmentName"

Comment: But in this case my mMap variable is null too.

Comment: Set `map = mMap` in `onMapReady` and after that you can do something with your map.

Comment: i write Log in onMapReady method and does not run

Answer (score 1):

have you generated the right Google Maps API key ?

And Google Maps needs the following permissions.

- `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` – To check network state whether data can be downloaded or not
- `INTERNET` – To check internet connection status
- `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` – To write to external storage as google maps store map data in external storage
- `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` – To determine user’s location using WiFi and mobile cell data
- `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` – To determine user’s location using GPS

*OpenGL ES V2* – Required for Google Maps V2

Comment: Yes. Last map launched in Activity

Answer (score -1):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    CHD = new LatLng(dlat, dlong);
    map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
            .getMap();
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(CHD).title("You Are Here"));
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(CHD, 15));
    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12), 2000, null);

}





<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
```